# Pinescript strategy not plotting

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm trying to create a plot to the chart based on the following conditions:

1. It's the second consecutive green bar to open above the 9 day MA line
2. It's oversold on the RSI

However, it doesn't seem to be plotting, I have a feeling the greenbc variable is returning false for some reason - any ideas?

```
strategy(title="Swing Strat", pyramiding=1, overlay=true, default_qty_value=2, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, initial_capital=100, currency=currency.GBP)

//Plotting SMA lines
MAPeriod9 = input(9, title="9 MA Period")
MA9 = sma(close, MAPeriod9)
MAPeriod180 = input(180, title="180 MA Period")
MA180 = sma(close, MAPeriod180)

plot(MA9, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(MA180, color=color.red, linewidth=1)

// Creating the RSI
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)

rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=70)
rsiOversold = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", type=input.integer, defval=30)

//get rsi value
rsiValue = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
isOverbought = rsiValue >= rsiOverbought
isOversold = rsiValue <= rsiOversold

//identifying green confirmation bar
MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA9)
entrypoint = barssince(MAcrossover)
greenbc = entrypoint==1 and MA9<open and open<close and open[1]<close[1]

//combining the green bar confirmation and oversold variable
tradingsignal = ((isOversold or isOversold[1]) and greenbc)

//plotting the entry point to the chart
plotshape(tradingsignal and greenbc, title="Entry Trigger", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=label.style_xcross, text="Entry Point")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotchar your individual conditions to get a sense of whether they are triggering in unison.

```
plotchar(entrypoint, 'Entry Point','')
plotchar(greenbc,'Greenbc','')
```

Etc.

The plotshape function needs a style of shape. `style=shape.cross`

The greenbc in plotshape is redundant because it is already used to create tradingsignal.